# Get Applications List in Windows 10/11 using Rust

Tags: rust, windows-10, command, command-prompt, rust-crates

I'm trying to get Windows 10 all installed Applications.

In Macos I can use `system_profiler` command to get installed applications and export it to json file then parse it to Rust, does Windows have any similiar command ?

Thank in advance

Comment: Take a look at [Get list of installed applications from Windows command line](https://superuser.com/q/68611/1755205), these are command-line answer but you should be able to get that and parse it